# XAMPP: MySQL does not start after crash

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

There are aready several questions regarding that MySQL fails to start when running XAMPP, but unfortunately I couldn't figure out a solution from these.

Here is my case:
I installed XAMPP for Linux 5.6.14-3 and when I ran it yesterday everything worked fine.
Today, I ran XAMPP again:

```
/opt/lampp$ sudo ./xampp start

Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.14-3...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

Then I open localhost in the browser bringing me to the xampp dashboard. There I click on the phpMyAdmin menu entry, which gives me:

```
Error

MySQL said: 
Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, 
and the server rejected the connection. 
You should check the host, username and password 
in your configuration and make sure that they 
correspond to the information given by the 
administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I think that I made sure that the control user has the right pass.

The problem rather seems to be that MySQL does not really start although it says 'ok' (see above). Since, when I stop XAMPP, I get:

```
/opt/lampp$ sudo ./xampp stop

Stopping XAMPP for Linux 5.6.14-3...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
```

Looking at the error_log of xampp, there is a single entry, which looks suspicious (though I don't really understand it), saying:

```
[Sun Nov 15 11:38:59.737875 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6217] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

So, if anybody is able to locate the problem or give me hints for a fix, I would really apreciate. Thanks already!

---

### Edit - problem "fixed" (without knowing, what I've really done, though)

Here's the MySQL error-log (located at /opt/lampp/var/mysql/[computername].err):

```
2015-11-15 15:52:44 10864 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 11011 ...
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 3813213 and 3813213 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 9929741 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-11-15 15:52:44 140410457307008 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace bitnami_joomla/jos_content_frontpage uses space ID: 14 at filepath: ./bitnami_joomla/jos_content_frontpage.ibd. Cannot open tablespace phpmyadmin/pma__bookmark which uses space ID: 14 at filepath: ./phpmyadmin/pma__bookmark.ibd
2015-11-15 15:52:44 7fb3db6e3780  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./phpmyadmin/pma__bookmark.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
2015-11-15 15:52:44 10864 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/[computername].pid ended
```

First try: I made a backup of the directory /opt/lampp/var/mysql/phpmyadmin/ and added

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

at the end of /opt/lampp/etc/my.conf. That gave me still the same error when starting MySQL again.

Next try was removing the file pma__bookmarks.idb from the directory, which had the effect that the error now complained about pma__favorites instead.

Finally, I removed all pma__*.idb-files and voila! MySQL is running, and I can access the phpMyAdmin-pages.

Works for me, though I don't know what was lost be removing the pma-databases? (They were not restored in any way, as it seems...)

Probably, the database-files were corrupted, when my computer went down, and they were still running!?

Answer (score 1):

You must check whether mysqld process exist in `top` and then either try to connect with `mysql` command line client or review MySQL Error log. Sometimes xampp may be confused by MySQL Server which e.g. comes pre-installed with OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't find any sql process running. Neither looking at the top output, nor 'ps -Al | grep -i sql' gives me anything on that. No other sql service running... But you made me search for the mysql-log and I somehow figured out a "fix". See my edit.

Comment: "Previous tablespace ... uses space ID ..." most oftem means that you just mixed .ibd files from different  MySQL Servers. (e.g. copied some files into datadir with existing old files). InnoDB is very sensitive to that, so you shouldn't copy individual files, etc.